# combine multiple expressions in R into one big expression

Tags: r, expression, eval

I am new to R expression handling. I am stuck with below problem. Any input is appreciated.

I am trying to generate two individual equations and combine them into one expression and pass it to an algorithm to find optimal value.

```
   OLD_PRICE    ELAST      Units    
 1  59.98        1.3        151     
 2  59.98        1.3        230
```

Code:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(df)){
    o[i] = df$OLD_PRICE[i]
    el[i] = df$ELAST[i]
    u[i] = df$Units[i]
    assign(paste0("l",i),(substitute((x)*(1-(x-o)*el/o)*u,     list(o=o[i],el=el[i],u=u[i]))))
}
```

I was able generate below two equations

```
l1 = (x) * (1 - (x - 59.98) * 1.3/59.98) * 151
l2 = (x) * (1 - (x - 59.98) * 1.3/59.98) * 230
```

And my objective function would look like this

```
eval_obj_f <- function(x){eval(l1)+eval(l2)}
```

I am trying to figure out how to do this dynamically. Like if I have a different dataset of 4  observations, how can I generate my objective function to be as below dynamically?

```
eval(l1)+eval(l2)+eval(l3)+eval(l4)
```

Comment: @user4966552: You do not have any "equations". You have two variables with the names `l1` and `l2` which are the expressions (in some loose sense) on the rhs of your "equations" above. You are hoping to have them evaluated within a particular environment where `x` exists in some form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to be using real R `expression`s and at the moment those are not expressions but rather `call`s. (Check with `is.expression` or `class`). I don't like the name "df" for dataframes since it is a function name as well, so I used "prdat":

```
 o <- el <- u <- numeric(2)  # if they don't exist, then the loop errors out
 for(i in 1:nrow(prdat)){
     o[i] = prdat$OLD_PRICE[i]
     el[i] = prdat$ELAST[i]
     u[i] = prdat$Units[i]
     assign(paste0("l",i), as.expression(substitute(x*(1-(x-o)*el/o)*u, 
                                                   list(o=o[i],el=el[i],u=u[i]))))
                        }

l1
#expression(x * (1 - (x - 59.98) * 1.3/59.98) * 151) # how expressions appear when printed.
l2
#expression(x * (1 - (x - 59.98) * 1.3/59.98) * 230)
exprlist <- list(l1,l2)

eval_obj_f <- function(x){sum( sapply( exprlist, eval, envir=list(x=x) ) )}
eval_obj_f(2)
#[1] 1719.569
```

This seems pretty clunky. I probably would have `apply`-ed a function over that dataframe and summed the results. I suppose it might be interesting to attempt the "compute on the language"-approach, but take alook at the code below which I think is more in keeping with the "R-way".  Seems more compact ... and expressive:

```
func <- function(x) {apply(prdat, 1, function(z) x*(1-
                                (x-z["OLD_PRICE"])*z["ELAST"]/z["OLD_PRICE"])*z["Units"] )}
> sum( func(x=2))
[1] 1719.569
```

This might be better than just using your code (but still a lot more clunky than the second method IMO):

```
exprvec <- expression()
o <- el <- u <- numeric(2)  
 for(i in 1:nrow(prdat)){
     o[i] = prdat$OLD_PRICE[i]
     el[i] = prdat$ELAST[i]
     u[i] = prdat$Units[i]
     exprvec[[i]] <- substitute(x*(1-(x-o)*el/o)*u, 
                                list(o=o[i],el=el[i],u=u[i]))
                        }  #substitute-value gets coerced to mode-expression
# Test
> eval_obj_f <- function(x){sum( sapply( exprvec, eval, envir=list(x=x) ) )}
> eval_obj_f(2)
[1] 1719.569
```

Comment: The question was "how can I generate my objective function to be as below dynamically?" with respect to l1+l2 vs. l1+l2+l3+... I would point out in your answer the role of `sum` to accomplish this.

Comment: Not sure I understand your concern. The `sum` function would collapse as many values as there were rows in the data.frame of coefficients. If you were concerned about the existence of an unspecified number of `l<n>`-expressions outside a list or list-like object then I would agree, and suggest to the OP that he instead add items to an expression-vector, rather than using `assign`.

Comment: Thanks BondedDust for the explanation and inputs.

Answer (score -1):

You can create functions that take an arbitrary number of arguments using ellipses:

```
eval_obj_f <-function(x,...){
  sum(sapply(...),function(expr) {eval(expr)})
}
```

For my example I'm moving your R expressions to a list

```
l=list()
for(i in 1:nrow(df)){  
  o = df$OLD_PRICE[i]
  el = df$ELAST[i]
  u = df$Units[i]
  l[[i]]=substitute((x)*(1-(x-o)*el/o)*u,list(o=o,el=el,u=u))
}
```

Now you can pass the list to your eval_obj_f function with the value of 'x':

```
x=8.76
eval_obj_f (x,l)
```

Comment: I hope you are working on an example to demonstrate this is useful. If not, then it's really just a comment-level contribution.

Comment: I didn't downvote it and SO is emphatically against requiring people to identify their reasons. I thought you might delete it after my question and even considered flagging it as "not an answer" but decide it was "useful". Somebody else apparently thought it was sufficiently "not useful" to give up one of their points to send a negative message.

Comment: Thanks. I'm new to this and eager to move up but clearly need to spend some more time generating useful responses.